# How to access multiple stores from single eBay developer account

Tags: ebay-api, trading, auth-token

I have one eBay developer account with sandbox and live keysets and token for each. Both are working well. Now I need to access one more store from this developer account (need to list items on another store using API).

So what do I need to do for that? I tried to generate another access token via "Get a Token from eBay via Your Application" but there I can enabled only one token!

Please help me to find how can I access another store from this single account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access any number of seller accounts/stores using single developer account.

You should generate Auth-token (rather than developer account) for each stores which you are going access from your developer account.

Auth-Token is the unique identifier for different stores in eBay

Generate new token by following the below steps,

Goto > https://go.developer.ebay.com/

Signin with your developer account credentials

[image: eBay dev account]
​
Generate token by clicking the UserToken for Production KeySet

This will redirect to eBay seller account, you should login with seller account to accept or allow your app to access seller account data.

Comment: I could not get the orders using the generated token there? Is that the token to use to get the refresh token? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is probably because the developer account remembers only one token- the last generated token. It doesn't remember all the tokens generated through the developer account. Basically you need to save the generated token in a secure way, because you won't be able to go back to the developer account get all the tokens generated through the developer account.